# Advance MQ FTE scheduler option

Tags: mq, websphere-mq-fte

we are using FTE agents for transferring files,
we want to configure scheduler transfer to work in a certain hours of the day,
so for example, if *.txt files is in the folder, transfer those files between 08:00AM to 12:00PM.
We tried so far several designed patterns (such as using ANT to determine the current hour and using trigger file which is different from the *.txt files) to solve the issue, but no success.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: I'd have expected your suggested approach using Ant to work. What problem did you run into?

Comment: We used ANT  in the pretransfer section. To  check if the current hour is in the time range for doing transfers. The problem was that if it is out of the time range we needed to cancel the transfer. And after canceling file transfer once the agent will ignore this file from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is currently an option in WebSphere MQ FTE/MFT that provides exactly what you are looking for. From my understanding, what you are basically requesting is the Resource Monitor functionality (see the link below) but with an extra to option to say only have the Resource Monitor active between two time periods.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7X_7.0.4/com.ibm.wmqfte.doc/resource_monitoring.htm

Currently, a Resource Monitor is active when the FTE/MFT agent hosting the Resource Monitor is running.

You would need a system that requests these transfers manually at the times you want them to be processed.

Perhaps you would like to consider raising a Request For Enhacement (RFE) against the product?:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?BRAND_ID=181